# A bit of trouble understanding a step in the deduction or the formula of the torsion?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading Struik's book on differential geometry. I'm trying to parse these equations:

> [image]

I understand how to do it, until the second line, where it seems he's assuming $n=\kappa^{-1}x''$ and $t=x'$ but I don't understand why this is true. It seems he took these assumptions from this previous page:

> [image]

What confuses me is that in this page, it seems he is assuming these equations hold for an arc-length parametrization, no? What am I misreading here?

Comment: I agree with you that these formulae make sens only for arc-length parametrization.

Comment: And curvature is always nonnegative, so one sentence is wrong. He said he was taking arclength as the parameter. What is your point? In (5-4) he said  that explicitly.

Comment: @TedShifrin But that formula works for non arc-length parametrizations, no? My doubt is that. It seems he was saying something for arc-length parametrizations and $(5-4)$ is a formula for any parametrization.

Comment: No, no. He wrote $x’=dx/ds$. $s$ denotes arclength. But the sign of curvature reference really bothers me.

Comment: @TedShifrin In another place of the book, he says that the curvature is nonnegative.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm still a bit confused. In the book, there is an exercise that asks me to compute $\tau$ for the curve $x(u)=(u,u^2,u^3)$. I did using this formula and got the exercise correct (according to the answers in the back of the book), but I didn't parametrize it by arclength. What happened?

Comment: The correct formula in the general case has a different denominator. Struik is a classic, but I don’t know the book myself. Check out my diff geo text, linked in my profile. Look in particular at exercise 11 in section 2 of chapter 1. The solution is at the back.

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh no, I discovered I messed up. The formula for arbitrary parametrizations is slightly different. Reading a bit further, I found [this](https://i.imgur.com/HrAtwvd.png). 
BTW: Yeah, [I printed your book and will read it later.](https://i.imgur.com/WzZxWqs.jpg) I'm just reading Struik because the professor who's lecturing me makes Struik-like questions in exams. But I found your book extremely well-written.